# There is no price.phtml in rwd/default/catalog/template/product

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to display the old price (regular price without discount) without taxes, but at the moment the configuration from the backend shows only the special price in the right way.

I checked the rwd/default/catalog/template/product/view.phtml and the content is rendered by `$this->getPriceHtml($_product);`. As I understood, the content should be found in the price.phtml, but there is no such file. Where can I find the HTML of the displayed price in the product page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rwd` package is supposed to have the file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`. I don't know if you mispelled the titled, but if you don't have it for some reason, it will fall back to `app/design/frontend/default/default` theme.

Comment: Ok thank you, I thought it would be in another location in the rwd theme. I found it in the `base/default` theme.

Comment: `price.phtml` wasn't added until 1.9.1.0, so it may not exist for gaspar, depending on what version of 1.9 he's using. Also, rwd/default/etc/theme.xml says `<parent />` which means it inherits from base/default not default/default. gasper you can turn on template hints and block hints to see how a page is being generated.